# QGIS Shapefile Emptying

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I've recently come across a problem with a few of my shapefiles on QGIS where they've lost all their data. They appear in the layers panel but the attribute table is empty, along with the feature count and extent being wiped clean. It had worked before but when I opened up the project the other day it was suddenly like that.

Any tips on being able to recover this?

Comment: Have you tried opening the shapefiles in another program? Or have you tried opening the attribute table (dbf) in something else to see if it is still populated with records? Without seeing your data, it's hard to say what is happening.

Comment: Did you click [Layer -> Create Layer -> New Shapefile Layer...](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/370449/2856)?